# Pass refresh and dashboard command to other modules

Tags: angular, design-patterns

I have an angular app which is behave as dashboard. And there are libraries which are behave as widgets of the dashboard. When i do refresh or any dashboard specific command in side the dash board, all the widget also refresh and get the dashboard command. I use .forRoot() static method to pass data a between dashboard app and widget libraries but is there any other better way to pass refresh kind of operation from dashboard app to widget

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are some better ways that three of them are:

01)  using the shared service which provide some get/set method to set and retrieve the date and all components can use that by injecting the common service.

02) Using the **RXJS** and observable to notify each other when ever is neeeded.

03) Using the **NGRX** and **Redux** pattern to shared some *states* in all of your app.